# Is it true that there was no such thing as a Hispanic-owned bank in the continental USA until 1969?

Tags: united-states, banking

I was doing some online research on the subject of minority-owned banks in the USA, and I stumbled across this passage on the [History](http://www.nationalbankers.org/history.htm) page of the website of the National Bankers Association.

> Diversity of minority banking began in 1962, when Los Angeles based
>   Cathay Bank became the first bank recognized as Asian-American.
>   Centinel Bank of Taos, New Mexico followed in 1969 becoming the first
>   US-mainland-based Hispanic bank. (Banco Popular de Puerto Rico,
>   headquartered in San Juan, is more than 100 years old.)

If I'm reading this right, that passage asserts that, until the year 1969, there literally was *no such thing* as a legally chartered bank, anywhere in the continental United States, which was wholly or mostly owned by one or more shareholders of Hispanic ancestry.

That idea greatly startled me when I ran across it earlier today. I would have thought there must have been several Hispanic-owned banks, long before that, particularly in the Southwest. (I.e., the areas which used to be part of Mexico.)

So now I'm asking the question posed in the title of this post. Or, to put it a little differently: Does anyone reading this know of a specific case, pre-1969, of a legitimate bank in the continental USA that was either a) *founded* by Hispanic owners, or b) was founded by someone else, but *later* had a majority of its shares bought up by one or more Hispanic businessmen (or businesswomen)?

Comment: A little googling turned up nothing, but I'd look in San Francisco in the Gold Rush era.  There were a ton of fly-by-night banks there and then.

Comment: Aren't most banks public companies, in which anyone (with sufficient funds) can buy shares?  So does the idea of a Hispanic-owned (or other ethnic group) even make sense?

Comment: I wonder if hispanic / Latino as ethic term was widely used  before? The ethic terms and their use for self identification are changed a lot during the late 20 th century.

Comment: @jamesqf -- I have no idea whether that is true, or has been since a certain time. For all I know, most commercial banks may have started out along the lines of "each member of a small group of investors puts up a pile of cash and owns shares in the bank. Public offerings of stock will only come much later, if ever." I simply know precious little about the history of banking in the USA (or elsewhere).

Comment: @Lorendiac: I would have thought there would have been banks in (the territory that later became) New Mexico, but finding an answer will require someone with better Google-fu than I have.  All I get are locations & hours for modern banks in Santa Fe :-(

Comment: IBC bank in Laredo was founded in 1966.  It is hispanic owned. I also think First National Bank of Mercedes founded in 1920 was hispanic owned.

Comment: @ed.hank When you say IBC Bank in Laredo "is Hispanic owned," that can be taken to mean: "Today, in 2018, it **is** owned by Hispanics . . .  but that doesn't mean it already *was,* 52 years ago, when it started."

Comment: @lorendiac - i am pretty sure it was hispanic owned from the start, but since i am not positive i just put it in the comment,  i actually emailed both banks to ask them if this was the case or not,  hopefully ill get a reply.

Comment: @ed.hank Remember that if you get it nailed down that at least one of those banks was "Hispanic owned" several decades ago, you'll have something to post as a real Answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think your first result is correct.  The structural impediments to Mexican-Americans founding a bank were significant. There were no banks in the region during the Mexican period. After the Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo and through the turn of the century, many Mexicans lost their land to Anglo settlers. In the 19th century Mexican-Americans did not have access to well-paying work. With the community largely in subsistence or wage labor, it would have been hard for them to capitalize a bank.

There were lots of Southwestern banks with Spanish language names before 1969, but they were not owned by Latinos. According to [Centinel's own story](https://www.centinelbank.com/about-us.htm), which jives with the Association text you posted, Mr. Romero had to appeal all the way to Washington, DC to get his new bank chartered:

> Eliu E. Romero grew up here in Taos County as his family had for 4 generations, herding sheep, subsistence farming, and speaking Spanish. He went away to school, served his country in the Navy and Merchant Marines, put himself through law school and returned to Taos. He wanted to practice law in his hometown and went to a bank seeking a loan of $50 for furniture for his new office. Despite his education, service to his country and roots in the community, he was turned down. It was a time in our country when discrimination was a common part of life, but experiencing the inequity, Romero vowed then and there to someday have a bank to service the needs of all the people in his community.
>
> After years of a flourishing law practice, Romero applied to the state for a charter to open a bank in Taos. That charter was denied, as was several other applications until Romero’s perseverance led him to Washington D.C. and a federal review of his application was approved by the FDIC and the state charter granted. Together, Eliu and his wife Elizabeth convinced 300 Taos County residents to help them capitalize the bank, and on March 1, 1969, Centinel Bank of Taos opened for business dedicated to serving all the people, cultures, and languages of the Taos County community.

Comment: I think I was working on the theory that there might very well have *already been* banks, owned and operated by Hispanic families or groups of businessmen, before the Mexican War caused huge chunks of territory to become U.S. soil -- more or less what U.S. citizens now call "the Southwest." I was thinking of such preexisting cities as San Francisco, Santa Fe, San Antonio . . . I'm very surprised by your assertion that "there were no banks in the region during the Mexican period." You may well be right; I am just *surprised!* Do you remember exactly where you acquired that bit of information?

Comment: I suggest the paper, _Land, Labor, and Production: The Colonial Economy of Spanish and Mexican California_. There were almost no Californian people in the pueblo of San Francisco, so I would not look there. _History of New Mexico: Its Resources and People_, pp. I:412, says "The history of banking in New Mexico dates from the year 1870...."

Comment: I followed your link to Centinel's website and read the full history. Something I noticed was that it says the Romero family eventually bought up everyone else's shares. But it doesn't say that the bank was mostly Hispanic-owned *before* that happened. In other words, it doesn't say that all (or even most) of the original 300 investors were Hispanic; it only says they were "Taos County residents." That seems to leave it up in the air regarding what demographic (if any) owned a majority of the shares when the bank began operating in **1969.**

Comment: That's a different question, but there are a lot of relevant articles in the Taos News from 1969.